# Is there something wrong with my OpenCV download?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to install **OpenCV3** through `homebrew` with contrib and python3. I have downloaded all the dependencies relatively quickly, but now it has been stuck on **make** for over half an hour. The only thing changing is the string between the red and

[image]

Comment: Yes the `make` command may take some time, also homebrew is not using `make -j` command to eat up all the cores, so probably the `make` is running on a single thread. It usually takes me approx 10 mins to make while I run `make-j4`, so I think you should wait a bit.

Comment: It's still going. Is there a way to speed it up or will I have to wait it out?

Comment: You can follow a manual installation procedure as described [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/)